# Security implications of running my website on my raspberry pi

Tags: web-server, security

What are the security implications if I try to run my website from my home from a raspberry pi as a total noob?

Is it fine if I just follow one of the more common tutorials or should I better pay a professional webhosting company to host my website?

Answer (score 2):

Renting a Virtual Private Server (VPS) is not necessary more secure than running on RPi, and you still going through almost the same processes in setting it up, unless you go for full hosting service.

In my opinion most of the online tutorials focus on how to setup a web server, but seldom have sufficient coverage on security and performance. In case you want to learn how to set up the hosting yourself on RPi, here is a [comprehensive guide](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2016/11/hosting-wordpress-on-raspberry-pi-a-complete-approach/) on how to setup a web server properly, and the site is running on a RPi 3.

Comment: The big advantage of using full hosting is that you have not opened a door for an attack on the rest of your home network and its data. so if you are not well versed in security it is money well spent to keep your banking info, passwords etc. safe.